# openshift application url returns 404 error

Tags: openshift

I am using openshift for opencart hosting. I created a url http://store-iosx.rhcloud.com/ . Due to few problems I thought of restarting from scratch. So I deleted the application using web console. Then recreated the url by adding a php 5.3 runtime. 
Following that whenever I visit the url http://store-iosx.rhcloud.com/ I get a 404 error ... I do not know how to debug this . Can anyone suggest anything ? more over it gets redirected to 
http://store-iosx.rhcloud.com/app all the time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It resumed working properly after the last git commit. Now I don't get any 404 errors.. I think it only takes time to reset the url.. A bit of patience is necessary.